# Find the most distant points on a curve

Tags: geometry, implicit-differentiation

Hy, I have to ask someone for help with this problem.

I have a curve with this implicit equation:

$$\left ( x^2 + y^2 \right )^2 = x^3 + y^3$$

I have to find the most distant coordinates from the center of coordinate system, and the most distant coordinates from y-axis.

The graph looks like this [Wolfram graph plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%5E2%20%3D%20%28x%5E3%20%2B%20y%5E3%29)

Do I have to use Lagrange method to solve this and how to set the equation up if so ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Lagrange method should work quite well with this. You need to maximize distance; but I'll give you a hint that it is easier to maximize the square of distance. So, you must maximize
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2
$$
subject to the constraint
$$g(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)^2-x^3-y^3=0
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I think you made a tiny mistake (x^2+y^2)^3 should be (x^2+y^2)^2...so is the following correct $$L(x,y,lambda)=x^2+y^2 - lambda*((x^2+y^2)^2-x^3-y^3)$$ ?

Comment: Looks good. And thanks for the correction.

Comment: This is how it looks in wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+%28x^2%2By^2%29^2+%3D+%28+x^3+%2B+y^3%29

Answer (score 1):

Convert to polar coordinates:

$$\begin{align}(r^2)^2&=r^3(\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta)\\
r&=\cos^3\theta + \sin^3\theta\qquad \because r\neq0\\
\frac {dr}{d\theta}&=-3\cos^2\theta \sin\theta+3\sin^3\theta\cos\theta=0\qquad
\quad \text{at max/min}\\
\sin\theta\cos\theta(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)&=0\\
&\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\sin\theta&=0\qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \Rightarrow \theta=n\pi\\
\cos\theta&=0\qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \Rightarrow \theta=(n+\frac 12)\pi\\
\sin\theta&=\cos\theta\Rightarrow \tan\theta=1\Rightarrow \theta=(n+\frac 14)\pi
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Checking each case with using $\frac {d^2r}{d\theta^2}$ will confirm that the maximum value for $r$ occurs at 
$$\theta=2n\pi, (2n+\frac12)\pi$$
where 
$$r=1$$
i.e. the most distant coordinates from the origin are, in $(x,y)$ terms, 
$$(1,0), (0,1)\qquad \blacksquare$$